# displaying pdf file in UIScrollview Horizontally

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview, uiscrollview

In a pdf file using UIWebView, I need to scroll horizontally instead of vertically. I have created UIScrollView in the form:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(2000, 420);
scrollView.bounces = NO;
scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = NO;
scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

and now adding the `UIWebView` in to UIScrollView as

```
[scrollView addSubview:webView];
```

it is not displaying the pdf file but if i give code like this

```
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

now it displays the file but it vertical scroll

I need to make it to scroll horizontally please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: R u loading your pdf from url?

Comment: Did you add the following:
    `[self.view addSubview:scrollView];`

Comment: yes im loading it from url and i have also added [self.view addSubview:scrollView] still its not working....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your code:

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(2000, 420);
scrollView.bounces = NO;
scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = NO;
scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[scrollView addSubview:webView];
```

add this also:

```
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

if you have not added it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge horizontal scroll with PDF in webview is not possible.you can use below opensource projects

[Leaves](https://github.com/vfr/Reader)

[Reader](https://github.com/brow/leaves)

Else you can use the QLPreviewController

Answer (score 0):

You can straight away put the pdf on UIWebView and if it is multiple pages it will scroll automatically. You can try the code below

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebview alloc]init];

webView.frame = "SET FRAME"

[self.view addSubView:webView];

// create a URL for the pdf file which is in you project

NSURL *pdfURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:"Name of pdf" withExtension:@"pdf"];**

[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pdfURL]];

//just to show the scroll indicators

[webView.scrollView flashScrollIndicators];
```

I do it this way....

Comment: after adding [webView.scrollView flashScrollIndicators]; what i need to do

Comment: this line is just used as an indicator that your webview is scrollable...    What I wanted to specify is that you dont need to add your webview over a scrollView.   I have edited my answer a little more. Please check now